MySQL Find all points stored as double that are within a passed polygon object
I have a MySql database which contains decimal lat/long points stored as follows:
CREATE TABLE `points` {
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `LATDEC` double(10,6) NOT NULL,
     `LONGDEC` double(10,6) NOT NULL
};
ALTER TABLE `points` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

I want to pass a JSON object of points representing a polygon to MySQL and have it return all points in the table which are within the passed polygon.
Example Object (a square):
[
{
    "lat": 21.901439302298186,
    "lng": -159.52874103166923
},
{
    "lat": 21.92134691642438,
    "lng": -159.52874103166923
},
{
    "lat": 21.92134691642438,
    "lng": -159.49270028575324
},
{
    "lat": 21.901439302298186,
    "lng": -159.49270028575324
}

]
I'm wondering if this is possible with MySQL.
So, for example, if I have a row with the values shown below, and I query based on the polygon above, it should return that row.
LATDEC = 21.90701850969123
LONGDEC = -159.5107259618992

INSERT INTO points (LATDEC, LONGDEC) VALUES ('21.90701850969123','-159.5107259618992');
I know that I can use something like:
Point(LATDEC, LONGDEC) to translate the point value.
I have tried to translate the JSON object into a MySQL polygon so that I can use ST_CONTAINS on it and am having no luck.
Example:
SELECT * FROM `points` WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON(21.901439302298186 -159.52874103166923, 21.92134691642438 -159.52874103166923, 21.92134691642438 -159.49270028575324, 21.901439302298186 -159.49270028575324)'), point(LATDEC, LONGDEC));

This always returns 0 rows even though it should return the row we just inserted.

Well I solved it (all it took was posting this question!).
The format of the polygon and the point function is longitude before latitude.
Also found that the POLYGON needed two sets of brackets.
Working SQL statement shown below:
SELECT * FROM `points` WHERE ST_CONTAINS( ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((-159.52874103166923 21.901439302298186, -159.52874103166923 21.92134691642438, -159.49270028575324 21.92134691642438, -159.49270028575324 21.901439302298186, -159.52874103166923 21.901439302298186))'), POINT(LONGDEC, LATDEC) );

Sure would be nice if there was a way to pass that JSON object directly to MySql, but I guess I have to parse it first.
